# Js stop scripts tags from running on condition

Tags: javascript, html

I want some of my scripts in my index.html page to run only on condition.
For example on specific version of IOS i want that the scripts after **general.js** not to run.

```
 <script src="general.js"></script>

 // stop here on condition
 <script src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="vendor/angularjs/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
 <script src="vendor/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js"></script>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208164/how-to-run-load-a-separate-javascript-file-selectively-from-inside-javascript

Answer (score 2):

### RequireJS?

Why don't you use something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). Have your main bootstrap script (your `general.js`) load all other scripts that depend on your condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Instead, insert the first `general.js` script as you would normally, and in your `head`, put a `script` that adds the files:

```
<script>
    var scripts = ['vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'vendor/angularjs/angular.js', 
 'vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js', 'vendor/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js'];
    if(condition) {
        for(i=0;i<scripts.length;i++) {
            $('head').append("<script src='"+scripts[i]+"'></script>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or in vanilla JS:

```
<script>
    var scripts = ['vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'vendor/angularjs/angular.js', 
 'vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js', 'vendor/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js'];
    if(condition) {
        for(i=0;i<scripts.length;i++) {
            script=document.createElement('script');
            script.src=scripts[i];
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    }
</script>
```

This creates an array of the new script directories and names, and loops through them, adding them to the head of the document dynamically.

Comment: This will not slow my app load time?

Comment: And this is not good solution for me because i need the scripts to be in the index.html cause i need gulp to use them.